# Merge two Git branches, but exclude certain files

Tags: git, merge

I am new to Git and I have some conceptual doubts.
My GitHub repository has 2 branches, `develop` and `production`. I code on the `develop` branch, and when it is ready I merge into `production`.

Some things are different and should stay different between the two branches. For example, there are two versions of the MySQL config, and they must not be merged. How can I handle this?

I use also Github to remotely deploy my application for my development environment (beta) and production environment (live).

Comment: I don't think you can manage that directly and only with GIT. How are you developing your application? If you use Spring, the best choice I see is using [Spring Profiles](http://blog.springsource.com/2011/02/11/spring-framework-3-1-m1-released/) and http://blog.springsource.org/2011/02/14/spring-3-1-m1-introducing-profile/

Comment: @mardavi I'm developing in `PHP` with `Yii Framework`, so I'm not able to use `Springsource`. I also use `AWS Beanstalk` GIT commands to deploy my application.

Comment: I believe you can use a gitignore file to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can have git ignore the files that you want changed.

Per this post http://blog.pagebakers.nl/2009/01/29/git-ignoring-changes-in-tracked-files/

`git index --assume-unchanged <file>`

https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-update-index.html

This will keep the file in the repo and ignore any changes to it.

You can also use a `.gitignore` file but that can still end up with changes being made.  And really is ideal for ignoring untracked files.